# Get only the last element of array mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have array in a document, and I try to receive the last element of this array.

My code is:

```
Post.find({_id:postId},{'comments':{'$slice':-1}});
```

this gives me all the object but the comments array contains only the last element.

on the other hand,

```
Post.find({_id:postId},{'comments':1});
```

give me only the comments.

I dont find how to combine the two commands together. How it can be done?

```
{
 "users":[],
 "comments":["string1","string2","string3"],
 "lastValue":"Wow"
 "name":"jow"
 "_id": {
    "$oid": "5747d6bdecfae9d0560077cc"
   },
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post sample document from your collection?

Comment: What's your objective? From which array you are trying to retrieve last element?

Comment: "comments":["string1","string2","string3"],

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to use mongodb (version 3.2) aggregation [$slice](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) like that:

```
Post.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: { 
      '_id.$oid': postId 
    }
  },
  { 
    $project: {
      comments: {
        $slice: [ "$comments", -1 ] 
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

In earlier versions of mongodb:

```
Post.aggregate([
  { 
    $match: { 
      '_id.$oid': postId 
    }
  },
  { 
    $unwind: "$comments"
  },
  {
    $group : {
      _id: "$_id.$oid",
      comment: { $last: "$comments" }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: This is almost works, I use the second, but their is problem with the _id it dont find the _id.

if I remove the _id:postId, I receive the last of every element..

Comment: @Alon in your example you search `{ _id: postId }`, but in the given example there is `$oid`. All you need is to specify valid collection identifier in the `$group _id` field and `$match` criteria. Updated the answer.

Comment: Your fix dont work, I found that use ,
_id:mongoose.Types.ObjectId(postId) works

Comment: @Alon oh, I couldn't know what you have in `postId`, makes sense too.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this helps.

```js
db.Post.find(
  { _id: postId },
  { comments: { $slice: -1 }, _id: 0, users: 0, lastValue: 0, name: 0 },
);
```

Comment: I hoped that their is something simplest, cause if I add things to the scheme I have to change this line also.

Answer (score 3):

In case of `Mongoose`, `slice` can work this way also,

```
model.find({ 
    // condition
})
.select('fields')
.slice('array', -1) // <------ Here
.then((data) => {
    // handle
})
.catch();
```

Just wrote pseudo code, as it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection_name.find({'name':'how'},{'comments': {$slice: -1}})
```