# Mongoose - update last element in array (update document with an aggregator)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My question builds off this: [Get only the last element of array mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475430/get-only-the-last-element-of-array-mongoose). However, I'm using Mongoose and want to also **update** a field in the last element of the array, not just retrieve it.

How can I modify the last element/object in the `rounds` array to change from `status: started` to `status: terminated`?

**Document to modify**

```
{
    "_id" : "8844d3f2d25f45df8105db1ab058d7d6",
    "rounds" : [ 
        { "status" : "offline" },
        { "status" : "paused" },
        { "status" : "started" }
    ],
    "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-05T21:21:58.823Z")
}
```

Seems like using negative indices would make this easy, allowing the n-1 element to be modified. I've seen many questions mention aggregation, but none modify the underlying data. I want to combine aggregation with updating a documenting.

Is it possible to use `$set` with a negative index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of v4.2 MongoDB does not have a straightforward way to update an array element by index.

However starting from v4.2 you can use [updates with aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/), which allow you to construct a new array based on the current array and replace the current array.

Instead of modifying the last element, you can construct a new array consisting of the first top `n - 1` elements combining with a new element `{ status: "terminated" }`.

You can achieve this by using [`$slice`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) to get the top `n - 1` elements and combine with the new element using [`$concatArrays`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concatArrays/)

This assumes the elements only contains the field `status` you you want to update a field of an array elements that contains multiple fields, you'll need to merge the updated field with the current element using [`$mergeObjects`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/mergeObjects/)

```
Model.updateOne({ // or updateMany with your condition
  _id: "8844d3f2d25f45df8105db1ab058d7d6"
}, [{
  $set: {
    rounds: {
      $concatArrays: [ // combine arrays
        {
          $slice: [ // get the top n - 1 elements
            "$rounds",
            { $subtract: [{ $size: "$rounds" }, 1] }
          ]
        },,
        [{ status: "terminated" }] // a new element to replace the last element
      ]
    }
  }
}])
```